# php, soap, SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: php, soap

у меня есть данный код

```
try{
    $SoapClientOCR = new SoapClient (
    "http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?WSDL"
    array(
        "trace"=>1,
        "exceptions"=>1
    )
);

}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
exit;
```

Но я получаю ошибку

```
SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?WSDL"
```

Подскажите, что не так и как реализовать код чтобы работало

в php ini я включил

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

все таже ошибка

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/12593651](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973010/12593651)

Comment: пытался, не работает

Comment: Какая версия php у вас? Только что проверил у себя ( 7.4.3) - всё работает

Comment: у меня версия php 5.6
с локалки у меня работает, а вот с сервера - нет

Comment: @DenysMaksiura а просто с вашего сервера запросить этот url удаётся? Каким-нибудь file_get_contents? Возможно дело в окружении.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин file_get_contents возвращает мне false, пока что не знаю что делать((

Comment: Вариантов много. Можно запросить url wget'ом или curl'ом, просто чтобы проверить, что он доступен с вашего сервера. В зависимости от ответа разбираться дальше. file_get_contents кидает варнинг в случае ошибки, можете включить обработку варнингов и посмотреть, что пошло не так.

Comment: когда обращаюсь через CURL получаю ответ "error code: 1006", я так понял что это нету прав

Comment: Права здесь не при чем. Вы делаете запрос на HTTPS, и SOAPClient не сможет подсоединиться и получить определение без настройки для этого. Смотрите пример ссылки в первом комментарии для того как настроить контекст.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я пробывал делать и на http, ошибка таже

Answer (score 0):

Я без проблем загрузил и создал SoapClient на сервере OpenServer v5.2.2 с PHP 7.2, с расширениями XML, XSL, SimpleXML, SOAP, XMLRPC, XMLReader, XMLWriter и др., используя ваш код:

```
<?php

try{
    $SoapClientOCR = new SoapClient (
    "http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?WSDL",
    array(
        "trace"=>1,
        "exceptions"=>1
    ));
    echo 'Successfully loaded SOAP' . PHP_EOL;
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```